# Fine tuning of the cosmological and gravitational constants

Tags: newtonian-gravity, universe, biology, cosmological-constant

Consider the gravitational constant $G$.  According to philosopher Robin Collins, cosmologists have been able to determine a region $W_r\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ for which the universe would have permitted embodied life forms had $G$ fallen into that region, i.e. had $G\in W_r$, and another region $W_R\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, containing $W_r$, for which the universe would not have permitted embodied life forms had $G\in W_R\setminus W_r$.  He goes on to claim that there are analogous regions $V_r$ and $V_R$ for the cosmological constant $\Lambda$.

However, he fails to explicitly identify either region $W_r$ or $W_R$, nor $V_r$ or $V_R$.

**Question 1(a).**  Are there really such regions $W_r\subset W_R$ that cosmologists have been able to determine that $G\in W_r$ yields a life-permitting universe and $G\in W_R\setminus W_r$ yields a non-life-permitting universe?

**Question 1(b).**  If so, what are $W_r$ and $W_R$, exactly?

**Question 2(a).**  Are there really such regions $V_r\subset V_R$ that cosmologists have been able to determine that $\Lambda\in V_r$ yields a life-permitting universe and $\Lambda\in V_R\setminus V_r$ yields a non-life-permitting universe?

**Question 2(b).**  If so, what are $V_r$ and $V_R$, exactly?

Also:

**Question 3.**  Could $G$ and $\Lambda$ have been any real value (whether life-permitting or not)?  If not, what could they have been?

Comment: Can cosmologists really make any comment on the general life-permitting nature of a universe?  They might be able to comment on life _as we know it_; but it's not clear to me how a cosmologist would ever be able to rule out life-permission in general in the universe.  That seems like a partially biological question, and also potentially unanswerable with our current knowledge.

Comment: @JMac I think "life as we know it" is good enough. In particular, Robin Collins is interested in "embodied moral agents" which means the life would have to be sufficiently complex to have large brains like ours. I think all that's necessary for this is to have an earth-like planet where such organisms could evolve.

Comment: Can you include a link to the place where Robin Collins discusses this?

Comment: @GenlyAi Sure: https://philpapers.org/rec/COLTTA-3 (see section 4.4 beginning on p244)

Comment: @BenW That seems like a flimsy assumption to me (for his definitions of "embodied moral agents").  I don't know how we would be able to establish that a world with different parameters couldn't manifest some sort of physical interaction which led to beings "who exist in a world with fixed laws and who can significantly affect each other for good or ill".  That seems like an _exceptionally_ hard thing to rule out given our limited understanding of intelligence.

Comment: @JMac In many cases sure it would be tough.  But according to Collins, certain values of $\Lambda$ or $G$ would lead to a universe that just collapses in on itself, or otherwise doesn't even permit the formation of stars and planets.  And in these cases it's hard to see how embodied moral agents could evolve.

Comment: @BenW Hard to see how it could evolve =/= proof that it couldn't evolve.  That's the part I'm struggling to understand how anyone would be capable of determining.